# Using gradle to publish all cached dependencies to a maven remote repository

Tags: maven, gradle, ivy

After trying to convince my team to continue to use ivy, they decided they still want to go a head and use an internal maven server using artifactory.  I have converted our ivy builds to gradle which is working fine.  The issue is we're pulling from several maven repositories as well as 1 internal ivy repository.  They would like to consolidate it so that every required dependency is hosted internally.  My thoughts on this, (please correct me if I am wrong) is if there is a way to publish all currently cached gradle dependencies to artifactory, this would in theory solve my issue.

Does any one know of a way of doing this?

In summary

Gradle cache -> publish -> artifactory